# Array loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I try to develop a simple program that prints all numbers in between 1 and 100 that divide by 3 without any residual and calculate the total sum

I did it with for loop:

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 3; i <= 100; i = i + 3) {
    document.write("<br/>" + i);
    sum = sum + i;
}
document.write("<br/>sum = " + sum); //1683
```

But I failed when I wanted to do it with array:

```
var numbers = [];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i = i + 3) {
    numbers[i - 1] = i;
}

for (var index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
    document.write("<br/>" + numbers[index]);
    sum = sum + i;
}

document.write("<br/>sum = " + sum);
```

Comment: Three Issues that I see immediately: `i - 1` will be `-1` in the first iteration. Incrementing `i` by `3` and using it as array index will cause *holes* in the array. `numbers` won't have `100` elements, so you should not iterate over it from `0` to `100`. What do you think `i` is in `sum = sum + i;` ?

Comment: why are you using two loops? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296674/array-loop-in-javascript/#41300246 try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding number to array

```
var numbers = [];
for(var i = 3; i <= 100; i = i +3){
  numbers.push(i);
}
```

summation and printing values

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    document.write("<br/>" + numbers[i]);
    sum = sum + numbers[i];
}
document.write("<br/>sum = " + sum); //1683
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this,

Array indexes should start from 0, that is why I have introduced another variable j=0

```
var numbers = [];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0, j = 0; i <= 100; i = i + 3, ++j) {
    numbers[j] = i;
}
```

**Update**

**First Issue:** 
In your code, ie. below code of yours,

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i = i + 3) {
    numbers[i - 1] = i;
}
```

In the first iteration,

```
i = 0;
numbers[0-1] = i // i.e numbers[-1] = 0;
```

and in your second loop, you are starting the index from 0

```
for (var index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
```

**Second issue:**

Also, if you don't use a sequential counter to fill the Array, you will end with `undefined` values for the ones you did not fill.

[image]

If you notice, the output after the loop, it says `numbers.length = 99` which is wrong it will not have that many items in it.

**Third Issue:**

In below code, even if you introduce a sequential counter, this is still wrong

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i = i + 3) {
    numbers[i - 1] = i;
}
```

because `i` should start with 3 instead of 0, otherwise you will end up with 34 elements in the array because `numbers[0]` will be 0;

**Fourth Issue:**

In this code,

```
for (var index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
    document.write("<br/>" + numbers[index]);
    sum = sum + i;
}
```

You don't actually have to loop it till 100, you already have the numbers array filled, so you just need to use `numbers.length`, like this

```
var len = numbers.length;
for (var index = 0; index < len; index++) {
    document.write("<br/>" + numbers[index]);
    sum = sum + i;
}
```

**A better way** to write this

```js
var numbers = [];
for (var i = 3, j=0; i <= 100; i = i + 3, j++) {
    numbers[j] = i;
}

var sum = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a+b);
console.log(sum);
```

The line `var sum = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a+b);` uses [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

Comment: That's only one of the issues.

Comment: In the second loop, numbers array can have 33 values. why are you looping till 100 iterations?

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in your code.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i = i + 3) {
    numbers[i - 1] = i;
}
```

1: array is 0 based. so first insertion into the array goes for a toss.

2: the number array created will have skipping index like 3, 6 ,9

```
for (var index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
    document.write("<br/>" + numbers[index]);
    sum = sum + i;
}
```

3: Here you are iterating index till 100 , you should iterate it till the length of the numbers array only.

when index is 1,2 
number[index] will become undefined.

4: sum = sum + i (i ??????)

You should try like this or you can also use push()

```js
var numbers = [];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0,j=0; i <= 100; i = i + 3, j= j+1) {
    numbers[j] = i; // array is 0 based.
  
}



for (var index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
    document.write("<br/>" + numbers[index]);
    sum = sum + numbers[index];
}

document.write("<br/>sum = " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexes in an array begin with zero.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i = i + 3) {
    numbers[i - 1] = i; // In the first iteration, there will be numbers[-1] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues i suppose.

```
var numbers = [];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i = i + 3) {
    numbers.push(i);
}

for (var index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
    document.write("<br/>" + numbers[index]);
    sum = sum + i;
}

document.write("<br/>sum = " + sum);
```

Also for array you can use:

```
for (var i in array) {
console.log(array[i]);
}
```

And I'm pretty sure, that array of number sequence is absolutely useless, if there is no other information in it.

Comment: *"You have several issues i suppose."* Maybe you can explain what they are?

Comment: See my code changes.
numbers[i-1] -> numbers[-1] in first iteration which doesn't exist.

And first for loop has 0-100 iterations and second has only 0-99.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var numbers = [];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i = i + 3) {
    numbers[(i-3)/3] = i;
}

for (var index = 0; index <  numbers.length; index++) {
    document.write("<br/>" + numbers[index]);
    sum = sum + numbers[index];
}

document.write("<br/>sum = " + sum);
```

Here is the fiddle i tried
https://jsfiddle.net/4ncgnd7c/

Answer (score 0):

This should work using a single loop

```
var numbers = [];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 3; i <= 100; i = i + 3) {
    numbers[i] = i;
    document.write("<br/>" + i);
    sum = sum + i;
}

document.write("<br/>sum = " + sum);
```